# How to do a wildcard search with mongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I'm new to mongo DB and I want to learn how to do a wild car search on a collection.
I have a data base like so:

```
term,value
greenwoods,1
blackberry,2
greenday,3
a Green apple,4
blacksmith,5
```

and my PHP code is:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$searchterm = "green";

$client = new MongoDB\Client;

$db = $client->database_test;

$wordcollection = $db->table_test2;

$document = $wordcollection->find(
        ['word' => $searchterm]
);

foreach($document as $doc)
{
        var_dump($doc);
}


?>
```

I want to find all the terms that contain the string green/Green so my desired result is:

```
greenwoods,1
greenday,3
a Green apple,4
```

What do I need to change in my code to get the result I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use regex

```
$document = $wordcollection->find(
'word' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($searchterm, 'i'),
);
```